# How do I activate a pre-receive hook in GitLab?

Tags: git, gitlab, githooks

I need to check each commit coming into GitLab and block any of them which have a certain file in. I used the documentation [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/server_hooks.html)

I have created a file named `pre-receive` in the `.git/custom_hooks` directory.

The file just has the contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
exit 1
```

Which, I believe, should reject any attempt to push code to the repo (?)

The file is owned by git and is executable:

`ls -a` gives the response:

> -rwxrwxrwx 1 git root 550 ...

The custom_hooks directory is also executable and owned by the git user.

But all commits go through without issue, the commit hook does not seem to activate in any way.

I do not see anything else in the documentation that I am supposed to do.
Have I missed anything?

Comment: Hi, the title of your question suggests you have an issue with a `pre-commit` hook, you say you set up a `pre-receive` hook (which is a *server side* hook, triggered on the server when a client issues a `git push`), and your question suggests you want to block pushes from your local machine which would be the role of a `pre-push` hook. Please check the [doc page on hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks), and clarify your question -- in particular : can you explain what you want to achieve ?

Comment: Hi, I want to check all files which have been changed and search for a particular one.  If it is present I want to block the commit.  After reading the documents (one of them being the one you linked to) I thought that the place to do this was server side in the pre-receive hook?  Am I mistaken?

Comment: Ok, can you update your question with that info ? "I want to ..."

Answer (score 2):

One way to do that is to set a pre-commit hook on your local machine, and check for the presence of said file among the staged files :

```
# .git/hooks/pre-comit :

#!/bin/bash

forbidden=$(git diff --cached --diff-filter=ACMR -- forbidden/file)

if [ -n "$forbidden" ]; then
    echo "*** rejecting commit, file '$forbidden' is present" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

One major benefit is : you (or other users) are informed *right now* that this file should not be committed, rather than later when the push is rejected.

Downsides are :

- this hook must be installed once per clone of your repo
- a user can skip that hook (uninstall it manually, modify the hook script, or run `git commit -n` to skip `pre-commit` and `commit-msg` hooks)

---

If you need to be 100% positive this file does not reach the central repo, one way to prevent this is indeed to set a `pre-receive` hook, but this hook must be set on the *server*.

You tagged your question `gitlab`, here is the documentation page to set such a hook :

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/server_hooks.html

You need to access your gitlab's install filesystem (e.g : ssh to gitlab's server with the admin account), and set the `pre-receive` hook in the appropriate project(s).

Note that, since a user can push a whole branch (or even several branches) in one go, you should check the presence of said file in *all new commits* pushed to the server, not just the tip of each branch.

Comment: Thanks.  I have followed that documentation but my problem is that the hook does not seem to activate.  Even when it just has 'exit 1' the commit is still allowed

Comment: You must either place the file in `.git/hooks/`, or set [`git config core.hooksPath [my custom path]`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-corehooksPath) ; file must be called `pre-commit` (not `pre-commit.sh`, not `pre-commit.py`, not ...), your own account must have the rights to execute this file.

Comment: Sorry I failed to clarify my meaning.  I need to put it on the server as it needs to be in place for all of the engineers, so I have added a 'pre-receive' file to my custom_hooks and hooks directory, neither seem to work :-(

Comment: I'll let you read gitlab's doc, then, check the doc for your version of gitlab.

Comment: I have read it.  I create a custom_hooks folder and put in a file called pre-receive.  It simply returns 'exit 1' but the commit is allowed through.  Is there anything needed that the documentation omits?  Are there underlying assumptions that I might have missed?

Answer (score 2):

Place this script in the hooks directory of your gitlab server.
Under hooks directory, create a new directory named - pre-receive.d and place the script file inside it.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Place this script in gitlab server directory -> <path_to_your_gitlab_server_root>/hooks/pre-receive.d
# Create directory,if it does not exists -> mkdir -p <path_to_your_gitlab_server_root>/hooks/pre-receive.d

# Get input data passed along pre-receive hook
read old_sha new_sha refname

# Default separator is ' ', change to ','
IFS=","

# Use env variable GL_USERNAME to get the matching details from users csv file
# This file can be easily generated from the database that you have configured for your gitlab instance.
# It contains records in following format - <username>,<user_email>,<user_name>
IFS=', ' read -r -a validuserarray <<< `grep -i "$GL_USERNAME," /tmp/gituser.csv `
valid_user_email=${validuserarray[1]}
valid_user_name=${validuserarray[2]}

# Get the last log user details from git log
IFS=', ' read -r -a incoming_committer_array <<< `git log -1 "$new_sha" --pretty=%ce,%cn | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`
IFS=', ' read -r -a incoming_author_array <<< `git log -1 "$new_sha" --pretty=%ae,%an | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`

# If no match found, fail the push
if [[ ${#validuserarray[@]} < 3 ]]; then
    echo "GL-HOOK-ERR: You are not authorised to perform this action."
    exit 1
fi

# Ensure no conflict markers are there
if git diff "$old_sha" "$new_sha" | grep -qE '^\+(<<<<<<<|>>>>>>>)'; then
    echo "GL-HOOK-ERR: Code has conflict markers. Please resolve and retry."
    exit 1
fi

# Validate author email ends with domain.com
if ! [[ "${incoming_author_array[0]}" =~ ^[A-Za-z0-9.]+[@]domain\.com$ ]]; then
        echo "GL-HOOK-ERR: Author email address ${incoming_author_array[0]} is invalid."
        exit 1
fi

# Validate committer email
if [ "${valid_user_email}" != "${incoming_committer_array[0]}" ]; then
    echo "GL-HOOK-ERR: Committer email address ${incoming_committer_array[0]} is invalid."
    exit 1
fi

# Validate committer name
if [ "${valid_user_name}" != "${incoming_committer_array[1]}" ]; then
    echo "GL-HOOK-ERR: Committer name ${incoming_committer_array[1]} is invalid."
    exit 1
fi
exit 0
```

For each push, gitlab will provide values - branch, old_sha, new_sha. In future, if you have any other use-case, simply put conditionals on these values.